# Why is re.sub not called re.replace

Tags: python

I've been writing Python for quite some time now, and so far it seems like the creators of the language put a lot of effort into readability of the code, a good example of this would be the `re` (Regular Expression) module.

Almost every method is clear in what it does:

- `re.search` Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern
- `re.split` Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern
- `re.escape` Escape all the characters in pattern except ASCII letters, numbers and '_'.
- etc..

Until we hit the following two methods:

- `re.sub`
- `re.subn`

These methods are meant to do a regex based **replace**, however the naming convention seem strange and out of place to me (especially when starting out, I had to constantly look the method names up). C# for instance does call the method `Regex.Replace`. <sup>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup>

Is there a reason behind naming these methods `sub` and `subn`?
Why didn't the developers simply name it `re.replace`?

Comment: Short form for `re.substitute`; intuitive. And because Python does not strive to be C#. I could even argue that `str.sub` should *replace* `str.replace` since the former is shorter. I'd rather `''.sub('', '').sub('', '')` than `''.replace('', '').replace('', '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional name of this regex command is substitute (or substitution). It comes from the original Unix [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29), where you use `s` to perform it, and this has been retained in [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed); perl [also uses the `s` command syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html).

From [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1)

> **The essential command: s for substitution**
>
> Sed has several commands, but most people only learn the substitute
>   command: s. The substitute command changes all occurrences of the
>   regular expression into a new value. A simple example is changing
>   "day" in the "old" file to "night" in the "new" file:
>
> `sed s/day/night/ <old >new`

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the real reason. :) I am just gonna delete my answer.